# PDO select and show data array with same date

Tags: php, arrays, group-by

I've made this code. To show the data based on same date (day)

```
        $group = array();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("
            SELECT *,date(date_added) as dateadded
            FROM rr
            ORDER BY dateadded DESC
        ");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        while ($res = $stmt->fetch()){
            $rtype = array();
                $rtype['type'] = "date";
                $rtype['date'] = date_format (new DateTime($res['dateadded']), 'M jS, Y');
                $rtype[] = $res;
            $result[] = $rtype;
        }
```

What I got as result from query sql

```
array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [type] => date
                [date] => Dec 18th, 2019
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [user_id] => 1
                        [status] => 1
                        [date_added] => 2019-12-18 13:44:30
                        [dateadded] => 2019-12-18
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [type] => date
                [date] => Dec 20th, 2019
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [user_id] => 2
                        [status] => 2
                        [date_added] => 2019-12-20 14:53:04
                        [dateadded] => 2019-12-20
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [type] => date
                [date] => Dec 29th, 2019
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 5
                        [user_id] => 3
                        [status] => 0
                        [date_added] => 2019-12-29 00:39:21
                        [dateadded] => 2019-12-29
                    )

            )

    )
```

There is some data that is not show as result in the same date.

What I want to show is like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => date
            [date] => Dec 18th, 2019
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [user_id] => 1
            [status] => 1
            [date_added] => 2019-12-18 13:44:30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => date
            [date] => Dec 20th, 2019
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [user_id] => 1
            [status] => 0
            [date_added] => 2019-12-20 14:53:04
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [user_id] => 1
            [status] => 0
            [date_added] => 2019-12-20 14:53:04
        )

)
```

The result is become an array like that with group by date (day).

How to get this result?
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: What's the purpose of `$group_date`? It's always an empty string.

Comment: I think that's is to group the data by the date (day). Can you show me how to achieve the right result?

Comment: You're already doing that with `GROUP BY dateadded`. There's only one row for each date.

Comment: if you post the exact output you are getting from your query, it would be really great.

Comment: How would comparing with an empty string cause the data to be grouped? Is that supposed to be the date from the previous row?

Comment: Sorry updated first post. It's not GROUP BY but ORDER BY

Comment: @dexter what you mean by exact output? I already show the output of my code in first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `$group_date` to the value of `$res['dateadded']` so you can tell when the date changes. There's no need to use `substr()`, since `dateadded` just contains the date without a time.

You should push `$res` onto `$result`, not `$rtype`.

```
$group_date = "";
$group = array();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
            SELECT *,date(date_added) as dateadded
            FROM rr
            ORDER BY dateadded 
        ");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while ($res = $stmt->fetch()){
    $rtype = array();
    if ($group_date !== $res["dateadded"]) {
        $rtype['type'] = "date";
        $rtype['date'] = date_format (new DateTime($res['dateadded']), 'M jS, Y');
        $result[] = $rtype;
        $group_date = $res["dateadded"];
    }
    $result[] = $res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works now. But you should change this " $result[] = res;" onto " $result[] = $res;"